# Show same video on two different places but only download it once?

Tags: html, html5-video

If I add two video tags with the same source it downloads the video twice.

```
<video>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video.mp4"></source>
</video>

<video>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video.mp4"></source>
</video>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0su5yn9L/

Check the Network tab in your dev tools.

I want it to work the same as with images where it only loads it once, regardless of how many times it is used. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't download twice. I see a `304/Not modified` status for those files in Chrome.

Is your "Disable cache" option checked in the dev tools network tab?

Comment: Yes, on subsequent requests it will be 304/Not modified but the very first time you load it will download it twice. Try making a force reload.